# Modifying the returned value of find_by_sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.8

So I am pulling my hair over this issue / gotcha. Basically I used find_by_sql to fetch data from my database. I did this because the query has lots of columns and table joins and I think using ActiveRecord and associations will slow it down.

I managed to pull the data and now I wanted to modify returned values. I did this by looping through the result ,for example.

```
a = Project.find_by_sql("SELECT mycolumn, mycolumn2 FROM my_table").each do |project|
  project['mycolumn'] = project['mycolumn'].split('_').first
end
```

What I found out is that `project['mycolumn']` was not changed at all.

So my question:

Does `find_by_sql` return an array Hashes?
Is it possible to modify the value of one of the attributes of hash as stated above?

Here is the code : http://pastie.org/4213454  . If you can have a look at `summarize_roles2()` that's where the action is taking place.

Thank you. Im using Rails 2.1.1 and Ruby 1.8. I can't really upgrade because of legacy codes.

Comment: Don't *think* that something will be slower/faster, benchmark both methods and *know* which is faster (and if it's fast enough to be worth it).

Answer (score 0):

Just change the method above to access the values, print value of project and you can clearly check the object property.

> ```
> The results will be returned as an array with columns requested encapsulated as attributes of the model you call this method from.If you call Product.find_by_sql then the results will be returned in a Product object with the attributes you specified in the SQL query.
> If you call a complicated SQL query which spans multiple tables the columns specified by the SELECT will be attributes of the model, whether or not they are columns of the corresponding table.
> ```

```
Post.find_by_sql "SELECT p.title, c.author FROM posts p, comments c WHERE p.id = c.post_id"
> [#<Post:0x36bff9c @attributes={"title"=>"Ruby Meetup", "first_name"=>"Quentin"}>, ...]
```

Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
a = Project.find_by_sql("SELECT mycolumn, mycolumn2 FROM my_table").each do |project|
  project['mycolumn'] = project['mycolumn'].split('_').first
  project.save
end
```